# Getting multiple errors while running NUnit Test script on Azure Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nunit, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am working with the NUnit test in visual studio. On visual studio 2019, it running fine with no errors. But when I am making an azure pipeline for the same I am getting the multiple errors in the VSTest step just after VSBuild step.

I am attaching the screenshot defining the errors.
[image]

Help me with suitable solution if any.

Comment: There's a NuGetCommand task in your build, if it's a NuGet restore command, please check its log see if you can find `Completed installation of System.Runtime.Loader 4.0.0` or anything related. If not, you might need to add a NuGet restore command task.

Comment: Does the 'use a different target framework' help solve the problem? If it does, you can [accept it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Or share us the latest developments it doesn't so that the community can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [comment on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22142#issuecomment-415838808):

> The problem is that System.Runtime.Loader is not supported on .NET Framework, this is a package that will only work on .NETCore App and UAP. We used to rely on a NuGet feature that wouldn't let this package install when targeting .NET Framework so you would get errors about this at compile time, but they changed this feature and now permit you to install the package and compile, so you now hit the error at runtime which is less than ideal. We could consider building a new version of this package that better stated that it is not supported on .NET Framework so that the incompatibility is found at compile-time.

The only solution seems to be use a different target framework.